# Converting Java List to another using java streams

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a class Test

```
public class Test{
  String codes;
  String field 1;
  ....
  String field n;
}
```

I have a list of test objects

```
List<Test> objects, code can be one or more with a comma separated
testObj1("A", "field1".."fieldn")
testObj2("B,C", ...)
testObj3("D,E,F", ....)
testObj4("G", ...)
```

Trying to convert this `list1` to new `list2` with each code A, B, C... to its own object by retaining the remaining fields.

```
List<Test>
testObj1("A", ....)
testObj2("B", ....)
testObj3("C", ....)

list1.stream().collect(Collectors.toList())
```

I achieved this using loops (Sudo code) but looking for better logic

```
for(loop thru list1){
  String[] codesArr = testObj1.codes.split(",");
  for (String code : codesArr) {
    //Create new Obj 
    Test obj = new Test(code, testObj1.copyotherfields);
    //Add obj to list2
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: I meant using Java Streams

Comment: In the future, please be explicit about what you are asking for.  I cannot know by your question whether there were performance issues, memory issues, correctness issues...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Stream.map` with `flatMap` as :

```
List<Test> finalList = list1.stream()
        .flatMap(e -> Arrays.stream(e.getCodes().split(","))
                .map(c -> new Test(c, e.getField1(), e.getFieldn())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This assumes that your `Test` class would have a constructor similar to the following implementation:

```
class Test {
    String codes;
    String field1;
    String fieldn;

    // would vary with the number of 'field's
    Test(String codes, String field1, String fieldn) {
        this.codes = codes;
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.fieldn = fieldn;
    }
    // getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this to:

```
List<Test> copy = list.stream()
                      .map(e -> Arrays.stream(e.codes.split(""))            
                                      .map(c -> new Test(c, e.otherField))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                     .findAny().orElse(...);
```

Which will stream through the given list, then stream through the `Array` yielded from `split()` and map to a new `Test` object and collect it to a `List`. It retrieves it through `findAny()`, which returns an `Optional<List<Test>>`, so I would recommend using `orElse` to retrieve a default value.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `map` function and then `flatMap` it to be like so:

```
List<String> testList = Arrays.asList("one,two,three,four", "five", "six", "seven", 
"eight, nine", "ten");

 List<String> reMappedList = testList.stream()
 .map(s -> {
     String[] array = s.split(",");
     return Arrays.asList(array);
 })
 .flatMap(List::stream)
 .collect(Collectors.toList());

 System.out.println(reMappedList);
```

Comment: I believe OP wanted a `List<Test>` not a `List<String>`